# SonarLint for Visual Studio showing http 403 error

Tags: sonarqube, http-error, sonarlint-vs

We have a self-signed certificate for our SonarQube site. Certificate is issued on domain name.
**Tools Version**
1. SonarQube - 6.3
2. Visual Studio - 2015
3. SonarLint - 4.3.0.3718
**Steps done for installing Certificate:**
1. Copied the certificate and installed into Trusted store.
2. Import the certificate into Java Key Store.

On connecting SonarLint with SonarQube Server following error is coming:
Connecting to SonarQube server: https://mydomainname/
Connecting to SonarQube server: Validating credentials
Connecting to SonarQube server: Retrieving organizations
Connecting to SonarQube server: Detecting server plugins
SonarQube request failed: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 ( ). 
Connecting to SonarQube server: Failed

Comment: Opening SonarQube in a browser succeeds?

Comment: SonarQube successfully runs in the browser.